# cakephp 2.X newline not working

Tags: php, html, cakephp, newline, cakephp-2.x

I've tried using html br tag, "\r\n" and  PHP_EOL yet my table data will not line break. I don't understand why it just appends it to a single line instead of giving a carriage return.

Here's an image of how it's currently showing my data:

[image: How it's currently formatting my data]

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Article</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
      foreach ($posts as $post):
    ?>
       <tr>
            <td>    
<?php
    echo $this->Html->link($this->Time->format($post['Post']['created'], '%d %b %Y', 'invalid') 
         . " - " . $post['Post']['article_title'] 
         . PHP_EOL . "<br />\n" . "\r\n" 
         . $post['Post']['article_link'], array(
        'controller' => 'posts',
        'action' => 'view',
        'inline' => false,
        'escape' => false,
        $post['Post']['id']
    ));
?>

            </td>

<td>
<?php
    echo $this->Html->link('Edit', array(
        'action' => 'edit',
        $post['Post']['id']
    ));
?>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->postLink('Delete', array(
        'action' => 'delete',
        $post['Post']['id']
    ), array(
        'confirm' => 'Are you sure?'
    ));
?>
           </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
endforeach;
?>
   <?php
unset($post);
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options like `escape` are ment to be passed in the `$options` argument of `HtmlHelper::link()`, ie the third argument. The second argument is ment to be used for the URL only.

Also note that when you disable automatic escaping, you should escape the relevant parts manually in order to avoid XSS.

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Time->format($post['Post']['created'], '%d %b %Y', 'invalid')
        . " - "
        . h($post['Post']['article_title']) // escape manually
        . "<br />"
        . h($post['Post']['article_link']),  // escape manually
    array(
        'controller' => 'posts',
        'action' => 'view',
        $post['Post']['id']
    ),
    array(
        'inline' => false,
        'escape' => false
    )
);
```

See also **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Helpers > Html > HtmlHelper::link()](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link)**

Comment: thank you for the reference material! shall try and carefully place escapes to avoid cross site scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Add `'escape' => false` to your link options to escape html characters.  This will allow you to use `<br>`.

```
    echo $this->Html->link($this->Time->format($post['Post']['created'], '%d %b %Y', 'invalid') 
         . " - " . $post['Post']['article_title'] 
         . PHP_EOL . "<br />\n" . "\r\n" 
         . $post['Post']['article_link'],
         array(
            'controller' => 'posts',
            'action' => 'view',
            'inline' => false,
            'escape' => false, // move this
            $post['Post']['id']
        ),
        array(
            'escape' => false // to here
        )
    );
```